# Firebase Auth not working in Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth (registering a new user) , it worked perfectly on the Main Thread but when i moved it to the background , Authentication always failed .
Here is the the method for creating a new user :

```
 public void createAccount(String email, String password) {
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(registerActivity.this, "bad",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        sr = false;

                    } else {

                        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        if (user != null) {

                            EditText etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
                            EditText etlname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLName);
                            String namez = etname.getText().toString();
                            String lnamez = etlname.getText().toString();
                            DatabaseReference mDatabase;
                            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                            Toast.makeText(registerActivity.this, "good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            String UID = user.getUid();
                            mDatabase.child("users").child(UID + "_lname").setValue(lnamez);
                            mDatabase.child("users").child(UID + "_name").setValue(namez);
                            sr = true;
                        }
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

and here is the AsyncTask :

```
 private class createInBack extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
//Executes the 'createAccount' method in background .
EditText etemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    EditText etpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    String email = etemail.getText().toString();
    String password = etpassword.getText().toString();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        createAccount(email, password);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(sr){
            Toast.makeText(registerActivity.this, "we good here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(registerActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

so what is the problem ?

Comment: I dont think you need to create a async task, because FirebaseAuth handles that for you.

Comment: That's what i did the first time , but i found a log on Logcat saying something like : too much work on the main thread.

Comment: Hmm.. I would not know why that is. But are you sure that onPostExecute() is really being called after onComplete() from createAccount()? Because I dont think it is and that might be messing things up for you, as you are instantly starting a new activity and canceling a Task which might still be in process.

Comment: Well , onPostExecute() is getting called after onComplete() but It's not even creating an account which is weird (isSuccessful() is False).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved ,
I found in the XML layout that i forgot to remove the "android:onClick" from the button.

Answer (score 0):

Linxy is right, it is not necessary to make an Asynctask for your goal.
Firebase solves that for you, look at a simple example.

```
private void loginAccount(String email, String password) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this,
                R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Autenticando...");
        progressDialog.show();
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                login.setEnabled(true);//button-ignore
                login.setAlpha(1f);
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    //Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Sesion iniciada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Email or password invalidate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("sesion","MaldatosH2");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

To create a user is the same xd